# Get Applicaton Path for iOS and Android

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I once used SQLite for my android application. I made a Queries.cs file where I had all the queries stored (createDatabase, insertDatabase etc). I had a string as a class variable where I stored the path ot the folder I wanted to put in my .db file. It looked like this:

```
private string folder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Now I want the same or at least the folder where the application sits in. But this time I need a way that'll be supported from iOS and form Android because it is necessary for this project. Do you know how I can do that?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unified way provided in Xamarin.Forms for this. You can leverage the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to reach it from your shared code and still differentiate per platform. This could look like this, define an interface in your shared code:

```
public interface IFilesystemService
{
    string GetAppRootFolder();
}
```

Now create an implementation on Android like this:

```
public class FilesystemServiceAndroid : IFilesystemService
{
    public string GetAppRootFolder()
    {
        return System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    }
}
```

For iOS the idea is the same, only the implementation may differ. You can, of course, extend this class as you like with the ability to read or write files for example.

Don't forget to adorn your namespace of the implementation with the `[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (FilesystemServiceAndroid ))]` attribute. Like so:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (FilesystemServiceAndroid ))]
namespace YourAppName
{
    public class FilesystemServiceAndroid : IFilesystemService
    {
        // ... code here
    }
}
```

You can now retrieve it in your shared code like this: `var path = DependencyService.Get<IFilesystemService>().GetAppRootFolder();`

Comment: [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (FilesystemServiceAndroid ))]

where do I have to put this in? I'm new to this, i'm sorry. Im still getting null back

Comment: I still seem to have an error going. But this time it is with the SQLiteConnection. Do you think you can help me out? :/
I've screenshotted the error: http://puu.sh/va49n/f4431e525c.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Dependency Service in order to get platform specific file paths. A great tutorial on how to use SQLite in Xamarin.Forms can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/) which can be used in platform specific code as well.